# Flow handling in interrupt driven UART - ATMEGA328P

Tags: c, arrays, interrupt, uart, strtol

I'm trying to implement interrupt driven UART communication with an ATMEGA328P. What I need to achieve is sending commands (char arrays) over UART in order to extract values to my variables in the `main` routine so that I can *program* a behaviour in my circuit.

The data I'm sending has this format: `2 255 0 255 0 0 255 1000` (it's for a RGB LED lamp)
This describes `long int` values for `mode`, 2 RGB colors and `duration`.

So far this is what I have in `main`:

```
while(1)
{
    if(rxFlag==1){
        char * pEnd;
        mode = strtol(buffer,&pEnd,10);
        Ri = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        Gi = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        Bi = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        Rf = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        Gf = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        Bf = strtol (pEnd, &pEnd,10);
        duration = strtol (pEnd,NULL,10);
        rxFlag=0;
    }

    switch(mode){
        case 1: // fixed color
            fixed(Rf, Gf, Bf);
            break;
        case 2: // yoyo pulse
            yoyo(Ri,Gi,Bi,Rf,Gf,Bf,duration);
            break;
        default:// red blinky
            fixed(0,255,255);
            _delay_ms(500);
            fixed(255,255,255);
            _delay_ms(500);
            break;

    }
}
```

And the ISR (interrupt service routine) that handles reception:

```
ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{   
   while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) );
   if (rxn==80){ // if BUFFER_SIZE is reached, reset to start of buffer.
       rxn=0;
   }
   buffer[rxn++] = UDR0; // increment rxn and return new value.
   if(buffer[rxn]=='\0'){
    rxFlag=1; // notify main of receipt of data.
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to update the variables' values only when I detect the `\0` at the end of the stream.

It's something like (in ISR):

- Read the incoming byte and store it in the buffer that is at most 80 bytes long
- If a `\0` comes in, let main know it has new data to process

In `main`:

- If there's new data, break the buffer into `long int` and store the values
- clear the new data flag
- act according to the new values.

The problem is that this isn't playing out as I wanted it and I'm kinda lost. I know my `switch` statement works correctly given the vars have correct values. I've narrowed down the problem to either the communication/buffer populating phase being broken OR the extraction of the variables' values being broken, but not sure which or if both.

Can anyone share any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Had some more time to think about this. Ignore my previous answer.

Make sure that your buffer is declared with the keyword *volatile*.

The fact that you're wrapping without performing any handling is also worrying. For a circular buffer, it's much better to keep track of head, tail, and the current size.

```
#define BUFF_MAX_BYTES 80

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef unsigned char boolean;

static volatile unsigned char buff[BUFF_MAX_BYTES];

static volatile unsigned char buffHead = 0;
static volatile unsigned char buffTail = 0;
static volatile unsigned char buffSize = 0;

boolean store_byte(unsigned char b)
{
    boolean success = TRUE;

    if(buffSize < BUFF_MAX_BYTES){
        buff[buffTail] = b;
        buffSize++;
        buffTail = (buffTail + 1) % BUFF_MAX_BYTES;
    } else{
        success = FALSE;
    }

    return success;
}

boolean eol_received(void)
{
    unsigned char prev_index = (buffTail == 0) ? BUFF_MAX_BYTES - 1 : buffTail - 1;
    boolean eol = FALSE;

    if(buff[prev_index] == '\0'){
        eol = TRUE;
    }

    return eol;
}

// Because strtol has no conception of where the buffer ends and wraps, you
// will have to create a modified version that can handle this case.
//
// A simple approach would be to calculate the length of your message, copy
// it to another buffer for parsing (advancing buffHead as you read bytes),
// and then call strtol on this new buffer.

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{   
    while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) );

    if(!store_byte(UDR0)){
        // Use a flag to inform main() of overflow, handle as appropriate
    }

    rxFlag = eol_received() ? 1 : 0;
}
```